# Display field on new dataframe based ordering and grouping data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset set and I am looking to display summarized results on a new data frame. So far I have the first two columns created which are all the unique IDs and the number of unique case numbers for that ID. Now I am looking to create additional columns that will display the "Code" for each case numbers as 1st case, 2nd case etc. columns. The logic is that the columns will display the the code that corresponds to a case number, if the case numbers are the same then it will first display the one with the earliest date, and then the later ones on the columns after it. And then the other "Code" for the different case numbers of the same ID after. Any help would be appreciated as I cannot figure out how to do it, thanks!

Desired result:

```
     ID        cases.unique        1st Case     2nd Case    3rd Case    4th Case
 1   100            1                715.10      724.50
 2   200            2                717.00      300.02      366.90      444.22
 3   300            1                717.00
 4   400            1                465.80      785.00
 5   500            1                309.00
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame("ID" = c(100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500),
                "Case Number" = c(1111, 1111, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1001, 9999, 1422, 1422, 1522), 
                "Date" = c("2013/07/15", "2013/09/23", "2016/06/21", "2016/09/18", "2016/10/20", "2016/08/06", "2017/08/21", "2016/08/23", "2016/08/24","2016/08/14"),
                "Code" = c(715.1, 724.5,717,366.9,444.22,300.02,717,465.8,785,309.0))
```

What I have so far:

```
x2 <- x %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(
    cases.unique = n_distinct(Case.Number)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `mutate` rather than `summarise`, and then `spread` the data after using `select` to remove unnecessary columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    cases.unique = n_distinct(Case.Number),
    case = paste("case", 1:n())
  ) %>% 
  select(-Date, -Case.Number) %>% 
  spread(key = case, value  = Code, fill = "")


# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID cases.unique `case 1` `case 2` `case 3` `case 4`
  <dbl>        <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1   100            1 715.1    724.5    ""       ""      
2   200            2 717      366.9    444.22   300.02  
3   300            1 717      ""       ""       ""      
4   400            1 465.8    785      ""       ""      
5   500            1 309      ""       ""       ""
```

Comment: great answer thank you! another question if possible is what if I have additional columns in the original dataset that I want to bring in?